# How to fix 'This loop will have at most one iteration' in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am getting `This loop will have at most one iteration` for following chunk of code. But when I Add else condition, I get an error.

```
def self.list_all_rentals_person_id(people, rentals)
  list_all_people(people)
  print 'ID of person: '
  person_id = gets.chomp
  rentals.each do |rental|
    return puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}" if rental.person.id == person_id
    else
      return puts 'No Rental Records Found'
    end
  end
```

But When I only use if and return, the if condition return. I won't get any error

```rb
 def self.list_all_rentals_person_id(people, rentals)
  list_all_people(people)
  print 'ID of person: '
  person_id = gets.chomp
  rentals.each do |rental|
    return puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}" if rental.person.id == person_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (4-space indent, or select and press ctrl-K or cmd-K); it is hard to see what your code actually is. But it seems you are trying to use `else` with a [modifier `if`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless). This is not possible: use a full `if` expression in such a case. The "at most one iteration" error from RuboCop is because `arr.each do |el| return f(el) end` is equivalent to `return f(arr.first)`, but is massively more confusing for the reader/maintainer.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Where does the `else` belong to? An `else` must either occur in an `if` block, or a `case` statement, or a `begin`-block, but even in the latter case, you would get a syntax error _else without rescue is useless_. I'm surprised thta your code is parsed as syntactically correct. While the method body indeed forms an implicit `begin ... end` scope, you are here in a code block (`do ... end`), which does not.

Comment: Actually, when I try the first version of your `list_all_rentals_person_id`, it does **not** compile at all, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have multiple small errors.

At first, Rubocop complains as directly on the first iteration of the loop, as return will end the loop. If you move the return after the loop, it will loop until it finds the first result.

```
def self.list_all_rentals_person_id(people, rentals)
  list_all_people(people)
  print 'ID of person: '
  person_id = gets.chomp

  rentals.each do |rental|
    return puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}" if rental.person.id == person_id
  end

  puts 'No Rental Records Found'
end
```

(notice: you can remove return if you want to return the last statement in a function in ruby, as it will always be the return value).

Your other problem is that you can't combine a single line if statement `return foo if bar` with an else on the second line.

```rb
return puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}" if rental.person.id == person_id
else
  return puts 'No Rental Records Found'
end
```

Should be written as

```rb
if rental.person.id == person_id
  return puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}"
else
  return puts 'No Rental Records Found'
end
```

Though, that will not please Rubocop in this case.

Answer (score 2):

An [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74455996/15261315) of what you've done wrong has been provided.

However, it seems you really want `Enumerable#find`.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [[4, 5], [2, 9], [7, 6]]
irb(main):002:1* if b = a.find { |x| x[0] > 6 }
irb(main):003:1*   p b
irb(main):004:1* else
irb(main):005:1*   puts "Nothing found"
irb(main):006:0> end
[7, 6]
=> [7, 6]
```

Translating this to your case:

```
def self.list_all_rentals_person_id(people, rentals)
  list_all_people(people)
  print 'ID of person: '
  person_id = gets.chomp

  if rental = rentals.find { |rental| rental.person.id == person_id }
    puts "Rentals:\nDate: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}"
  else
    puts 'No Rental Records Found'
  end
end
```

Or you may want to use `Enumerable#select` to get *all* rentals that matching your criteria.

```
def self.list_all_rentals_person_id(people, rentals)
  list_all_people(people)
  print 'ID of person: '
  person_id = gets.chomp

  matching_rentals = rentals.select { |r| r.person.id == person_id }

  if matching_rentals.empty?
    puts 'No Rental Records Found'
  else
    puts "Rentals:"

    matching_rentals.each do |rental|
      puts "Date: #{rental.date}  Book: #{rental.book.title}"
    end
  end
end
```